# How to do two tasks at the same time in asyncio or multithreading?

Tags: python, multithreading, asynchronous, python-asyncio

I'm trying to achieve a task that requires real-time interaction, for example: **A message (response) is received - it needs to be acted on at the same time.**

I tried the multi-threading module but couldn't really get to work, so I'm demonstrating an idea here as to what I'm intending to accomplish.

Here, a message "Hello" and "How are you?" needs to be outputted at the same time as it would in 2 separate threads.

This doesn't execute "Hi, how are you?" and just keeps outputting "Hello".

```
import asyncio
from time import sleep

async def respond():
    while True:
        sleep(1)
        print("Hi, how are you?")

async def main():
    asyncio.create_task(respond())
    while True:
        sleep(1)
        print("Hello")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Yes, I need something like two threads because while one has a "loop" which is actively checking for a message - I want to create a task in another thread which will then send message to that loop to do the rest.

Comment: The problem in your example is that you need to await asyncio.sleep instead of using time.sleep. But whether you should use asyncio or something else really depends on your actual problem. Are you waiting for I/O to complete? Do you have asyncio-aware libraries you can use?

Answer (score 0):

try to use `python-worker` ([link](https://pypi.org/project/python-worker/))

```
import asyncio
from time import sleep
from worker import async_worker

@async_worker
async def respond():
    while True:
        sleep(1)
        print("Hi, how are you?")

@async_worker
async def main():
    await respond()
    while True:
        sleep(1)
        print("Hello")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
```